# Server 16.04: Run 2+ parallel commands or multiple terminals

Tags: 16.04, command-line, server

I'm trying to run 2 parallel commands on the server with Ubuntu Server 16.04 set on it. Or maybe (which is very doubtful) having 2+ terminals, so I could run each command in different "window".

I know that it's possible to do that by creating SSH connection and running as many commands as I want via PuTTY or some similar programs. But is that possible to achieve the same result without these extra apps (or commands like `ssh` on Ubuntu Desktop)

Comment: If you run `command &` the '&' at the end of the command causes the command to run in the background, and subsequent commands don't wait for it to complete.  This could be what you're after but I'm not sure.

Comment: @guiverc I tried running the command with `&` at the end but it doesn't exit to the new line. So I can't run the second program after the first in this case

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but for example if ran `uptime; uptime; uptime` it would run each 'uptime' one after the other.  While it's a bad example (the command is so quick it will be finished before the next starts), the command `uptime& uptime& uptime&` would (if the command took more time) run the three commands in parallel and in the background (assuming 3+ cores) & command line returns. It's easier to detect if you use commands that take awhile - though output can be jumbled on screen ... it's probably not an ideal example; but the '&' runs in background instead of ';'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, '&' sends the process in background. An illustrative example of & and ; is

```
(sleep 2; echo "2") & (sleep 3; echo "3") & (sleep 2; echo "hi") &
```

if you don't like the endlines:

```
(sleep 2; printf "2") & (sleep 3; printf "3") & (sleep 2; printf "hi") &
```

The three compound commands run in parallel in the background. You can just replace them with your scripts, or make use of the & operator as you see fit.